# Help identifying the method of construction my house uses

Tags: walls, construction, interior, materials

Walls are approximately 13.75” thick. Listed as stone and stucco. 
I saw what looks like water damage in a corner and the, what I’m assuming is plaster, had been damaged. I cut the paint to expose underneath (pictured below).
[image]

I decided to chip away to see if I can find any issues. It appears that it has a stone layer on the bottom, with a wood board (damage can be seen below) on the interior side. Above that is this dirt-looking brown stuff. Normally it seems pretty solid (based on the edges where it wasn’t effected), however, it is weak and crumbly around the damage.
I would like to see if anyone can help ID the materials/methods so I can go about appropriately repairing.
[image]

Edit to add: apologies - It looks like I forgot the date. Built in 1964. Appraisal lists “block/Stucco.” Located in Arizona.

Comment: research `adobe building`

Comment: Where are you? Adobe would make sense in the Southwest US.

Comment: Interesting, I am in the SW. I hadn’t considered adobe. Was that still common in the 60s?

Comment: An adobe abode?